# Joomla - page visible only if registered user first visit

Tags: joomla, acl, joomla-extensions

I would like that a page appear only one time for each registered user. (For each user that is logged and access to the page) the second time the page is no longer visible.

Comment: Is it the same page for all users or a personalized page?

Comment: You need to create a [system plugin](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/System). On first visit, save the time or just boolean, that user has visited this page. Next time check if this value exists for user and deny viewing of page if true.

Comment: thanks ! it is the same page for all users.Registered user who logs on for the first time to this page sees it in a certain way. The next time not.